# Deleting record in many-to-many table

Tags: doctrine, symfony, many-to-many, dql

I'm following the security chapter of the Symfony 2 book.

There's is an example with a table `USERS` and `GROUPS`. There is a **many-to-many** relationship between `USERS` and `GROUPS`, which creates in the database a table called `USERGROUPS`.

What I want is to delete a record from `USERGROUPS`, for example:

```
DELETE from USERGROUPS WHERE user_id = 1 and group_id = 1
```

I don't know how to do this since I don't have an `USERGROUPS.php` table file.

Using DQL, for example, I want to be able to do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'DELETE FROM AcmeStoreBundle:UserGroups ug WHERE ug.user_id = :user 
    and ug.group_id = :group'
)->setParameter(array('user' => $userid, 'group' => $groupid));
```

I hope you get the idea.

Then, how do I remove from this table?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doctrine thinks about the data as objects, rather than as table rows. So, in Doctrine terms, there are Group objects (which hold the Group's users, among other things) and there are User objects (each one of which has a property storing the Groups that the user is in). But there are no UserGroup objects. The idea of Doctrine (and any ORM system) is to let the developer forget about these intermediate tables that the database might need but that aren't necessary in terms of the program's object model.

So what you want to do is load up the relevant User object, remove the group from it's $groups property, and persist the modified User object. (Or vice-versa, i.e. load up the relevant Group object and remove the User from it.) DQL might be able to handle this, but I think it's easier to do it without DQL as DQL's DELETE statement is for deleting whole objects, not modifying their properties.

Try:

```
$user = $em->find('User', $userId);
$user->removeGroup($groupId); //make sure the removeGroup method is defined in your User model. 
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush(); //only call this after you've made all your data modifications
```

Note: if you don't have a removeGroup() method in your User model (I think Symfony can generate one for you, but I could be wrong), the method could look as follows.

```
//In User.php, and assuming the User's groups are stored in $this->groups, 
//and $groups is initialized to an empty ArrayCollection in the User class's constructor
//(which Symfony should do by default).

class User
{
    //all your other methods

    public function removeGroup($group)
    {
        //optionally add a check here to see that $group exists before removing it.
        return $this->groups->removeElement($group);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ethan. Thank you SO MUCH! It worked :)
Why symfony didn't generate this method automatically? I believe it's a really common task to delete something from your many to many table.

Comment: Yeah, I've always wondered why symfony doesn't generate remove methods too (since it does generate addMethods). Glad it worked!

Comment: What if there are 1,000,000 records in the many-to-many table related to this user and I need to delete only one? Doctrine will load all the records?

Comment: @AlexeyKosov Doctrine will load the collection in this case, hydrating each & every one of those objects. In this case DQL and/or QueryBuilder are the way to go.

Comment: On this particular case a phan error `Call to method removeElement on non-class type` was driving me nuts and your comment `and $groups is initialized to an empty ArrayCollection in the User class's constructor` helped me solve it: my property wasn't initialized in the constructor. Thank you so much!

Comment: This will only remove 1 record, what if I want to remove all records of USERGROUP related to particular USER ??

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Ethan's answer, one-way remove is not working. For such `manyToMany` relationship, you have to call the `remove` methods from both entities, for example,

```
$user = $em->findOneById($userId);
$group = $em->findOneById($groupId);

$user->removeGroup($group);
$group->removeUser($user);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Is your solution equivalent of Delete from Table where col1=<val> and col2=<val>? Does it make query in Joined Table?

Comment: It seems to be like that