# Deleting record from many to many table doctrine symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can add record to `many to many` table `tag_post` successfully but I'm not able to remove any records from `tag_post`. **Please bear in mind I only want to remove records from `tag_post` not the record from table `post` itself**.

I have 3 tables `post`,`tag` and `tag_post`. tables `tag_post` contains relation between `post` and `tag`. the fields in table `tag_post` are :

- tag_id
- post_id

**Mapping file for post:**

```
    oneToMany:
    tagPostAssociations:
        targetEntity: Mockizart\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\MockblogTagPost
        mappedBy: "post"
        cascade: ["persist","remove"]
```

**Mapping file for tag:**

```
    oneToMany:
    tagPostAssociations:
        targetEntity: Mockizart\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\MockblogTagPost
        mappedBy: "tag"
        cascade: ["persist","remove"]
```

**Mapping file for tag_post:**

```
    manyToOne:
    post:
        associationKey: true
        targetEntity: Mockizart\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\MockblogPost
        inversedBy: "tagPostAssociations"
    tag:
        targetEntity: Mockizart\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\MockblogTag
        inversedBy: "tagPostAssociations"
```

**My code for test:**

```
    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogPost',6);
    $b = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogTagPost',['tagId' => 20,'postId' => 6]);
    $post->removeTagPostAssociation($b);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($post);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

**My tag_post entity:**

```
public function __construct($tag, $post)
{
    $this->tagId = $tag->getId();
    $this->postId = $post->getId();
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->tag = $tag;
}
```

**My post entity:**

```
public  $tagPostAssociations;

public function __construct() {
    $this->tagPostAssociations = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addTagPostAssociation(MockblogTagPost $tagPostAssociations)
{
    $newTag = $tagPostAssociations;
    $this->newTags[$newTag->getTagId().$newTag->getPostId()] = $newTag;
    $hasTagPost = $this->hasTagPost($newTag);

    if (!$hasTagPost) {
        $this->tagPostAssociations[] = $tagPostAssociations;
    }

    return $this;
}


public function removeTagPostAssociation(MockblogTagPost $tagPost)
{
    $this->tagPostAssociations->removeElement($tagPost);


    return $this;
}

public function getTagPostAssociations()
{
    return $this->tagPostAssociations;
}
```

I only post codes that I think related to the case. if you want to see more code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test your setup, however I believe you've mixed up your understanding of the `cascade` attribute with Doctrine. See, if you did something like:

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogPost',6);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($post);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Then Doctrine would recognize that you are deleting the `$post` in question and would cascade operations to all of the associations that have the "remove" cascade rule defined, which would delete the `tag_post` entry in question. However you're *not* deleting your `$post`, so you must manually remove the `tag_post` after taking it out of your object:

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogPost',6);
$b = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogTagPost',['tagId' => 20,'postId' => 6]);
$post->removeTagPostAssociation($b);
// This may need to come after the persist, haven't tested
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($b);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($post);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

This is obviously cumbersome if you're constantly removing entries, so perhaps an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) could automate this process for you.

One other thing to note is that you may be able to get away with just removing the `tag_post` and not touching your `post` or `tag` objects at all:

```
$b = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MockizartBlogBundle:MockblogTagPost',['tagId' => 20,'postId' => 6]);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($b);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Reason being is that all of the foreign reference columns "live" in the `tag_post` table, meaning there would be no integrity violations by simply removing a `ManyToMany` reference. Only thing is any loaded `post` or `tag` object would have out-of-date `tagPostAssociations`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I read this link (answered by @ethan ) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653493/deleting-record-in-many-to-many-table) but he don't need to call remove()

Comment: @MuhammadRifkiMockie That question you refer to uses a true `ManyToMany` association, where you've decided to abstract a `ManyToMany` association with two `ManyToOne`s to a single entity so you can add attributes to the association. Doctrine does not handle the latter natively.

Comment: I tested what you said above and it works. but I still don't get it why I can add to `tagPostAssociations` without `persist()` it separately but not able to remove them without `remove()`. do you have any link about this ?

Comment: @MuhammadRifkiMockie It is because `removeTagPostAssociation()` is **NOT** the same as `remove()`. The `addTagPostAssociation()` function also does _not_ trigger the `persist()` function either, it is your usage of `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist()` that triggers the `persist` cascade. Therefore, `removeTagPostAssocation()` does not trigger the `remove` cascade. I have no literature for you [except for the relevant documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Comment: In another code I only using `flush()` without `persist()` and it works (when updating post record and adding new record for `tagpost`). it is a must to call `persist()` when adding new record (add new `tagpost` when update `post`), isn't it?

Comment: @MuhammadRifkiMockie I'd have to see the other code. You are likely calling the `persist` cascade somewhere which triggers the rest.

Comment: here is my code : [gist](https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/f1b40ac673deb2e57f50) if you don't mind to see the code :) Thank you @sjagr